# Parallel Python for-loop iterating over list of function arguments

Tags: python, list, for-loop, parallel-processing

I need to parallelize a Python `for` loop in which for every iteration, a function (that takes two arguments) is called that returns two results, and then these results are appended to two different lists. The `for` loop iterates over two lists of arguments.

So say I have the following code:

```
def my_f(a, b):
    res1 = a + b
    res2 = a * b
    return res1, res2
    
# lists of arguments
args1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]  
args2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
    
res_list1, res_list2 = [], []
for i in range(len(args1)):  # loop to parallelize
    res1, res2 = my_f(args1[i], args2[i])
    res_list1.append(res1)
    res_list2.append(res2)
```

The result should be

```
res_list1 = [6, 8, 10, 12]
res_list2 = [5, 12, 21, 32]
```

How would I go about making it run in parallel?

I am aware that in C/C++ one can just use `#pragma omp for` to obtain a parallel for. Is there anything similar in Python?

I am using python 3.8.5 on Linux, but I need to have it work on any OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python's `multiprocessing.Pool` feature to achieve your result. Here's the link from the docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) However, instead of using `map`, you are going to want to use `starmap` because you are passing more than one argument. Here is how I would do it:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def my_f(a, b):
    res1 = a + b
    res2 = a * b
    return res1, res2
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]  
    args2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]
        
    
    res = []
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        res = pool.starmap(my_f, zip(args1,args2))

    res_list1 = [r[0] for r in res]
    res_list2 = [r[1] for r in res]
```

Firstly, notice that the main code is in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. This is super important to Python parallelism because Python will actually create new processes and not threads. Anything in the `if` block will only be run by the main process.

Secondly, I converted your two lists into a single iterable using the `zip` method. This is important because the `starmap` function must have the arguments in the form of a tuple.

Finally, the last few lines convert the `res` list into two lists like your example had. That is because the `res` output is actually a list of tuples.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach using [concurrent.future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) so you can easily switch between [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) and [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) in case your workload will change in the future:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
  

def worker(args):
    a, b = args
    res1 = a + b
    res2 = a * b

    return res1, res2


def main():
    args1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    args2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]

    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        result = executor.map(worker, zip(args1, args2))

    a, b = map(list, zip(*result))

    print(a, b)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```